# How can I get exception details in grid view using server mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a DevExpress GridView bound to an EntityInstantFeedbackSource. The data loads and pages just fine. My problem occurs when I try to group by a column in the view. All of the rows in the grid disappear and I get an error tooltip. The text in the tooltip is cut off, however, meaning I can't see all of it.

Taking suggestions from DevExpress support site, I've added a handler to the default tooltip controller's BeforeShow event so that I can show error messages returned from the data source. This allows me to see the entire error message. The problem is, the message says

> Database error - An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

The exception is long gone by the time this tooltip is presented in the view. Is there any way to capture the information it contains before it is gone?

I tried making the debugger throw all CLR exceptions by checking "Thrown" on the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" item in the Debug->Exceptions dialog in VS2010, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with some help from DevExpress. To see the exception at runtime, I needed to turn off "Just My Code" in the Visual Studio debugger, as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Turns out I was using an outdated version of MySQLConnector .NET. A known grouping bug in older versions produces the following error:
"Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K1' in 'field list'"